# Swift: use inOut parameter in escaping closure

Tags: swift, api, core-data, escaping, closures

I have the following method:

```
private func retrieveFromAPIAndMapToCD<T: Decodable & CoreDataMappable, R: NSManagedObject>(endpoint: Endpoint, object: T.Type, cdObjectType: R.Type, storedObjectList: inout [R]) {
    
    API.client.call(endpoint, expecting: [T].self) { (result, objects) in
        switch result {
        case .failure:
            print("Unable to retrieve objects")
        case .success:
            guard let objectResponse = objects else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for object in objectResponse {
                    object.mapToCoreData()
                }
                self.appDelegate.saveContext()
                self.updateLastSavedDate(object: T.self)
                self.fetchObjectsFromCD(object: cdObjectType.self, objectList: &storedObjectList)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without pasting too much unnecessary code, my issue is that within this API call (which comes from a library helper method we use to handle API responses) I need to set storedObjectList which is a variable defined within the scope of the current class.

However, when I do this I receive an error stating:

```
Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'storedObjectList'
```

I'm trying to find a way around this so that I can still pass in storedObjectList here. I hit this method for 3 different objects, hence why I am trying to make it generic to avoid code repetition. This is the last part that I cannot get to work. I would like to avoid having some kind of a switch statement based on the object type passed in as R because this will limit the reusability of this method in the future.